# In IRB, can I view the source of a method I defined earlier?

Tags: ruby, irb

If I define a method in IRB, is there any way to review its source later in the session?

```
> def my_method
>   puts "hi"
> end
```

Several screens of output later I'd like to be able to write something like

```
> source my_method
```

and get back:

```
=> def my_method; puts "hi"; end;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [pry](http://pry.github.com/). There is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails) about it (released this same week!) and it shows you how to show the code by using `show-method`.

Answer (score 20):

Not in IRB but in [Pry](http://pry.github.com) this feature is built-in.

Behold:

```
pry(main)> def hello
pry(main)*   puts "hello my friend, it's a strange world we live in"
pry(main)*   puts "yes! the rich give their mistresses tiny, illuminated dying things"
pry(main)*   puts "and life is neither sacred, nor noble, nor good"
pry(main)* end
=> nil
pry(main)> show-method hello

From: (pry) @ line 1:
Number of lines: 5

def hello
  puts "hello my friend, it's a strange world we live in"
  puts "yes! the rich give their mistresses tiny, illuminated dying things"
  puts "and life is neither sacred, nor noble, nor good"
end
pry(main)>
```

Comment: irb implements this feature in 2022. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78222356/5989200) for details.

Comment: yeah, it stole pry's code with no attribution

Comment: This is not an appropriate place to discuss such a thing, but AFAIK the code of irb and that of pry are different enough... I'm not sure why you've used such a strong word.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Ruby 1.9.2 and a newer version of the [sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify) gem than available on Rubygems.org (e.g. build the source from GitHub), you can do this:

```
>> require 'sourcify'
=> true
>> 
..   class MyMath
..     def self.sum(x, y)
..         x + y # (blah)
..       end
..   end
=> nil
>> 
..   MyMath.method(:sum).to_source
=> "def sum(x, y)\n  (x + y)\nend"
>> MyMath.method(:sum).to_raw_source
=> "def sum(x, y)\n    x + y # (blah)\n  end"
```

Edit: also check out [method_source](https://github.com/banister/method_source), which is what pry uses internally.

Comment: As I said you need Ruby 1.9.2 and a version of `sourcify` that's newer than the one currently available on Rubygems.org (I built mine from the Git repo). I updated my post to make this more clear.

Answer (score 5):

What I use is [method_source](https://github.com/banister/method_source) I have method *code* which is basically my wrapper for this gem. Add method_source in Gemfile for Rails apps. And create initializer with following code.

```
  # Takes instance/class, method and displays source code and comments
  def code(ints_or_clazz, method)
    method = method.to_sym
    clazz = ints_or_clazz.is_a?(Class) ? ints_or_clazz : ints_or_clazz.class
    puts "** Comments: "
    clazz.instance_method(method).comment.display
    puts "** Source:"
    clazz.instance_method(method).source.display
  end
```

Usage is:

```
code Foo, :bar
```

or with instance

```
code foo_instance, :bar
```

Better approach is to have class with in /lib folder with your irb extension, than you just *require* it in one of initializers (or create your own)

Comment: Super handy, thanks! Portable & self-contained, will work regardless of whether or not `pry` happens to be installed

Answer (score 0):

After [irb v1.3.5](https://github.com/ruby/irb/releases/tag/v1.3.5), irb itself implements `show_source` and its alias `$`. You can show method definitions like the following.

```
irb(main):001> IRB::VERSION
=> "1.12.0"
irb(main):002* def foo
irb(main):003*   puts "hi"
irb(main):004> end
=> :foo
irb(main):005> show_source foo

From: (irb):2

def foo
  puts "hi"
end

=> nil
irb(main):006> $ foo

From: (irb):2

def foo
  puts "hi"
end

=> nil
irb(main):007> # For instance methods
=> nil
irb(main):008* class A
irb(main):009*   def bar
irb(main):010*     puts "hello from A"
irb(main):011*   end
irb(main):012> end
=> :bar
irb(main):013* class B < A
irb(main):014*   def bar
irb(main):015*     puts "hello from B"
irb(main):016*     super
irb(main):017*   end
irb(main):018> end
=> :bar
irb(main):019> $ B#bar

From: (irb):14

def bar
    puts "hello from B"
    super
  end

=> nil
irb(main):020> $ B#bar --super

From: (irb):9

def bar
    puts "hello from A"
  end

=> nil
```