# How to return (to the Interactive Ruby Shell) the code that runs when a method is called

Tags: ruby

In other languages I have seen ways of showing the code that makes up a function or method. Is there a way to do this in the IRB?

Example, in R, you can simply type a function without the `()` and it will tell you what code will run when the function is called. Simple example [here](https://rextester.com/BOUJ26149)

Is this possible in IRB? (preferably without [pry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190146/in-irb-can-i-view-the-source-of-a-method-i-defined-earlier) or any other gems)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393096/how-can-i-get-source-code-of-a-method-dynamically-and-also-which-file-is-this-me/46966145#46966145

Comment: @mrzasa I dropped the code blocks into irb and the first one errors with `TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String)`. The second one doesn't error. But when I call `.source` on an existing method, it errors. E.g. `class.method` and `"class".method` both error.

Comment: @mrzasa I guess what I'm saying is I can read the answer but I don't know what to actually do with it. Do I copy the code into irb? Can you give an example of how to call the method?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966145/580346:

```
method = SomeConstant.method(:some_method_name)
file_path, line = method.source_location
# puts 10 lines start from the method define 
IO.readlines(file_path)[line-1, 10]
```

If you want use this more conveniently, your can open the Method class:

```
# ~/.irbrc
class Method
  def source(limit=10)
    file, line = source_location
    if file && line
      IO.readlines(file)[line-1,limit]
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Paste above code to your irb and then call `YourConstant.method(:your_method).source`